# Getting undefined response to API Request through Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, web-api-testing

I am unable to understand that why am I getting the undefined response to my code API request through mocha. Any leads will be appreciated Attaching the codes picture and code itself too.

```
import supertest from "supertest";
import { expect } from 'chai';
const request = 
    supertest("https://api.staging.graana.rocks/api/");
let a;

describe('Users', () => {
    it('GET /users', () => {
        request.get('city?home=true').end((err,res) => {
            expect(res.body.data).to.be.not.null;
            a = res.body.data;
            console.log(res.body.data);
            console.log(a)
            
        });
    });
});
```

[Code's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJYLA.png)

I am really stuck any leads would be helpful. Thank You in advance.

Comment: @lpizzinidev I want to do it through https link considering I have to automate api tests.
Also I used the same syntax for another public api https link I got correct response

Furthermore tried to check my api link on postman, it is returning data properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass query params using the `query()` method.
The test is described to call the `/users` end-point so you should change the `.get()` path accordingly if you need to test that path.

```
describe('Users', () => {
  it('GET /users', async () => {
    const res = await request.get('/city').query({ home: true });
    expect(res.body.data).to.be.not.null;
    a = res.body.data;
    console.log(res.body.data);
    console.log(a);
  });
});
```

Also, change your `supertest` declaration to (remove the trailing `/`):

```
const request = supertest("https://api.staging.graana.rocks/api");
```